# need a java program to detect if an input character is a vowel

Tags: java

**Requirement:**

- Ask the user to type a ***single character*** from the alphabet.
- Indicate then that this character is vowel or consonant, depending on the user's input.
- If the user input is not a letter (between a and z or A and Z), **or is a word with length> 1, type an error message**.*

**Problem:**
can anyone help me to fix this code for the bold one , i have to use character not String.

````
public class Ush {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("put an character of alphabet  : ");

        char s = sc.next().charAt(0);
        int s1 = s;
        String s2 = Character.toString(s);



        if(s2.length() > 1){
            System.out.println(" Mistake !");
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: You check the length of the char, it can only be 1, you need to check the length of `s` before taking the charAt(0)

Comment: @azro and how can i do that, i know that char take only one character but when i exectue the program and i type two ore more characters he doesn't show me the error message

Comment: `String s = sc.next()` check its length, then take the first char and do you stuff

Comment: @azro Thanks !! Dude you are a legend <3

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of ways of doing it but you can simply check if there are more chars on your `Scanner`, ex:

```
if (sc.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(" Mistake !");
}
```

This way, if you scanner has another input, you will get the Mistake printed.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Ush {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

            System.out.println("put an character of alphabet  : ");

            char s = sc.next().charAt(0);
            int s1 = s;
            String s2 = sc.next();


            if(s2.length() > 1){
                System.out.println(" Mistake !");
            }
        }
    }
```

But you can optimize your program as below,

```
public class Ush {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

            System.out.println("put an character of alphabet  : ");

            String s2 = sc.next();
            char s = s2.charAt(0);
            int s1 = s;


            if(s2.length() > 1){
                System.out.println(" Mistake !");
            }
        }
    }
```